# Requirement of center tap in PoE applications

Tags: poe

Why do we connect the power (48 V) and ground (return path for PoE power) on the center taps of transformer for PoE applications?

Can't it be directly connected to TD+ & TD- pins of the transformer? If it is legitimate, what is the difference between two topologies?

Comment: Putting power directly onto a data line means data is shorted to power.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a schematic diagram of the ethernet magnetics.

The DC current flows from the PoE injector into the center tap where it splits.

Half of the current flows through the transformer winding in one direction, and the other 1/2 of the current flows in the opposite direction, thereby no net magnetic field is created by any changes in the DC current.

No net magnetic field means that no signal is injected into the ethernet data stream.

Similar thing happens at the other end.

[image]from: avnet.com

Comment: seems non-standard.  the standard has the powered device accepting power on the spare pair also.

Comment: @Jasen AFAIK it is the standard for the old 802.3af Mode A.

Comment: some magnetic field is injected by the mismatch of the two legs of the pair, the key thing is the sum of the fluxes through the two windings is sufficiently small not to saturate the core.